# How I can get map<string, int> from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I am trying to get map from dll c++ 
So I have to get the map and parsing it as dictionary in C# side.
I have tried to do below steps and it is not worked.

C++ code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) map<string, int> createMap(string &fileName) {
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    vector<string> bitsLine;
    bool headerEnded = false;
    string line;
    int i = 0;
    int length = 0;

    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        if (headerEnded) {
            bitsLine = split(line, ',');
            signalsMap.insert({ bitsLine.at(0), length });
        }
        else {
            if (line.find("HEADER_END") != std::string::npos) {
                headerEnded = true;
            }
        }
        length = infile.tellg();
        i++;
    }
    return signalsMap;
}
```

C# code:

```
Dictionary<string, int>  x =  createMap("C:/users/asalah/source/repos/WindowsFormsApp3/WindowsFormsApp3/RR_Test2_3.csv");
```

Comment: C# is NOT C++, it is just a "scripting language" where the script is the bytecode (here called CLI "Common Language Intermediate"), like Java.  So, it (C#) couldn't understand native types like `map`, you must Marshal it using the Platform Invoke, or something like that.

Comment: This will more than likely fail even if the calling code is C++, let alone C#.  Understand that `std::map` may be implemented differently or have different internals depending on compiler, compiler options.  In addition, heap allocation becomes an issue between modules, etc.

Comment: `Dictionary` is not a structure, but a class. You cannot generate it using dllimport. Consider creating a struct with `string[] keys` and `int[] values` that could be passed and in the c# code after the call has been made create a Dictionary from that struct.

Comment: @user9335240 C# isn't a scripting language, and the bytecode is not C#. In fact you can compile C# programs without there ever being bytecode.

Comment: @Ameer Many possible solutions. Many different wants for C# code to consume a C++ DLL, before you even get into how to serialize the map. This makes the question far too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to this question is unfortunately "you shouldn't". You shouldn't export STL types from a dll in the first place, much less try to marshal them in C#. An STL type may vary in memory layout from compiler to compiler, C++ runtime to C++ runtime. It could cause very fragile code. So if you export a C function it should take a `const char*` instead of `std::string` for example.

What you could do could be to just marshal each key and value as they are made available. The advantage of this is that you don't have to do any work with memory management and it's fairly simple to integrate in what you already have, though I'm making no statement about performance.

Here is a short C++ and C# example to get you going on such a solution if it is of any help to you:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void doFoo(void(*adder)(const char*, int32_t))
{
    adder("Test", 346);
}
```

Below is the C# code for consuming this API. It should simply just add "Test" with the value 346 to the dictionary and nothing more. It does this by invoking a callback function which is a native shim  around Dictionary.Add for the specified instance of the dictionary.

```
namespace Eff3
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    delegate void DictionaryAdd(string key, int value);

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("TestDll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern void doFoo(DictionaryAdd callback);

        static void Main()
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            doFoo(result.Add);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this on my machine, and I built the DLL in Visual C++ 2017 in x64 and disabled "Prefer 32-bit" in C#.

Comment: Worked , Thanks <3